# Image Viewer in Android

Tags: android, pdf

I'd like to create an eBook reader app for Android but in my case, all books are basically just scanned images compiled in PDF format.

But after a lot head banging and several tests it turned out that PDF rendering on Android is awfully slow, especially on low-end devices.

So I'm wondering if theres a way to show these images directly instead of PDF but still show them as a "book", so technically an "image viewer" but the user doesn't notice. Is it possible?

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF isn't made up of images, they're vectors, there's a way to convert that to image files.

There are a couple open-source java PDF to Image converters though like:

http://www.jpedal.org/

http://code.google.com/p/pdfonejava/

I'm sure there are more but you'll have to find them.

Then just cache those images and there are several open-source android image viewers like:

http://code.google.com/p/android-mysample-project/source/browse/trunk/ARCamera/src/net/android/sample/imageviewer/ImageViewer.java?spec=svn9&r=9

Is this what your aiming for or am I completely off?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    PdfReader reader;
    File file = new File("/sdcard/vineeth/anni.prc");
    try {
        reader = new PdfReader(file.getAbsolutePath());
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.getXrefSize(); i++) {
            PdfObject pdfobj= reader.getPdfObject(i);
            if (pdfobj == null || !pdfobj.isStream()) {
                continue;
            }
            PdfStream stream = (PdfStream) pdfobj;
            PdfObject pdfsubtype = stream.get(PdfName.SUBTYPE);
            if (pdfsubtype != null && pdfsubtype.toString().equals(PdfName.IMAGE.toString())) {
                byte[] img = PdfReader.getStreamBytesRaw((PRStream) stream);
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(file.getParentFile(), 
                String.format("%1$05d", i) + ".jpg"));
                out.write(img);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```